# Can checkresiduals() in R only be used for time series models?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create additional graphs to ones made by plot() to assess assumptions in my linear model. I came across check residuals() in the package forecast, but I'm not sure if using that requires your object to have time on the x axis (my model has density here). Does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help page for `forecast::checkresiduals` makes it clear that its (first) argument must be

> either a time series model, a forecast object, or a time series
> (assumed to be residuals)

so that, yes, the x-axis must be time. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.15/topics/checkresiduals